# Opening a .doc file, which is actually an HTML file, as a .doc file

Tags: microsoft-word, html, libreoffice, openoffice, documents

My software generates `.doc` files which are actually HTML files but with the ".doc" extension.

When I open them in Microsoft Office they open as a `.doc` file and the user does not know that it is actually an `.html` file.

However, when I open them in LibreOffice or OpenOffice they are opened as a text file showing the HTML markup.

How can I create a HTML file with a ".doc" extension that opens as a `.doc` file in LibreOffice?

Here is a sample of one of the files:

`<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title>" </title><style>table, tr, th, td { border: 1px solid #333; border-collapse: collapse; direction: rtl; } table { margin: 10px; } th, td { padding: 10px; } </style></head><body dir="rtl"><h1>" </h1>: 01.07.2018 - 31.07.2018<br /><br /><h3> </th><td></td></tr></table><br /><h3> : </h3><table><tr><th> </th></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table></body></html>`

(Please note that I use Hebrew UTF8 inside the files.)

Comment: The example html you posted opened as a text document in my LO, no html tags at all. Try to reset LO settings to default

Comment: As @Alex states, using LibreOffice Writer v. 6.1.0.3, the file is displayed as HTML, showing just a quote as heading1 and date-time below. Writer displays the file this way whether it has .DOC or .HTML extension.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Anyhow the problem was in the encoding. I started using Windows-1255 and all problems gone. Should I answer my own question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, thanks. Anyhow the problem was in the encoding. I started using Windows-1255 and all problems gone.

```
  $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'ISO-8859-8', 'UTF-8');
```

ISO-8859-8 and Windows-1255 are basically the same.